# Vagrant VM shell script automation for mariadb to backup databases on shutdown trigger

Tags: shell, mariadb, centos8

How would I have the following executed on CentOS 8.1 automatically prior to each shutdown?

```
mysqldump --user=root --passwordpass --lock-tables -e --all-databases > ~/dbs.sql
```

Likewise, how would I re-import them automatically upon startup?

Comment: Do you also want to erase the disk?

Comment: No, overwrite the existing databases on startup